# generate uri from dynamic @RequestMapping in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi

I'm using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to generate our api from an openapi spec.

The generator creates controllers with an `@RequestMapping("${openapi.appname.base-path:/api}")` annotation.

So far so good. But when I try to build an URI for a specific method of this controller, things start to get messy.

I have the following method in my service

```java
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createAwards(Awards awards) {

        AwardsEntity entity = AwardsMapper.toEntity(awards);
        entity = repository.save(entity);

        UriComponents uriComponents = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName(
                AwardsApiController.class, "getAwardsById", entity.getId()).buildAndExpand();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uriComponents.toUri()).build();
    }
```

This code runs without an exception, but the resulting URI in the Location header looks like this

```
http://localhost:8080/$%7Bopenapi.oscarVoting.base-path:/api%7D/awards/3
```

The `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` treats the `${openapi.oscarVoting.base-path:/api}` part as an path parameter and url-encodes it.

Is there any way to fix this?